# How to remove proxy footprints? Firefox works but wget not

Tags: 18.04, proxy

It is a wifi connection with no proxy... I supposing that I removed all proxy configs, and Firefox is working fine. But any terminal command line not works:

- `curl --verbose http://w3c.org` say *(5) Could not resolve proxy: http*.
- `wget http://w3c.org` say *failed: Name or service not known. wget: unable to resolve host address ‘http’*.

About wget error, I tested [this change `resolv.conf` suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24821755/287948) but no effect.

---

### NOTES:

- changing URL to `https://w3c.org`  the error messages not changes (say "http").
- I am using UBUNTU 18 LTS.
- `sudo apt update` is working (!).

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, yes, all proxy there! How to remove it?  I deleted all changes that I was do in `.profile`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

will show if there is anything set in the environment. This will remove the variable if one was set:

```
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

(You can bypass proxy with curl with the `--noproxy` option)

`.wgetrc` might have a `proxy=on` in the settings file. Also check `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/environment` for any variables that set a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, `unset` is working (!), wget alive again!  Any problem if I have `locate .wgetrc` with nothing?

Comment: no mine was empty too :) good job getting it working :)

Comment: hum... Not solved: https://askubuntu.com/q/1161331/439867