# How to stop wrong-proxy exporter?

Tags: 18.04, proxy

With [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161264/439867) I unset all "residual" proxy values... 
And I supposed to "purge" all configs (edited all [config files described here at "Config procedures used"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57206176/287948):  I removed  definitions from `.profile`, etc.

But now, **as magic** something is setting strange values that I never set,  seems mixing/concating things: when I show `env | grep -i proxy`

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://http://pac._domain_/proxy.pac:8080/
https_proxy=http://http://pac._domain_/proxy.pac:8080/
http_proxy=http://http://pac._domain_/proxy.pac:8080/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
HTTPS_PROXY=http://http://pac._domain_/proxy.pac:8080/
```

How to really purge all proxy generators, including the magic?

---

PS: the magic perhaps comes from Firefox forms or WiFi manager?